# How to improve server-side rendering when process complex requests?

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have got Angular + Universal project with server-side rendering (SSR). 
Everything works fine but one of my pages is a catalogue with almost 10000 items with hundreds of properties inside. Sometimes it can take 5s to process a request and to get search results back.

The problem I am facing is that server-side doesn't render long requests and retrieves almost blank page. As one of the possible workarounds, I tried to put API requests to ngOnInit to get results first and render page after. It works fine but new a user needs to wait to see a page and long processing pages reduce SEO pages!

Another interesting thing found is to try to identify whether browser or server processing the page.

use isBrowser check:

```
public isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
```

Firstly, I imported:

```
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
```

Then, injected PLATFORM_ID in constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)
```

So now I have 2 calls one for servers:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(!this.isBrowser){
      this.directionsService.getDirections(this.region).then(data => { this.directions = data; });
    }
  }
```

another for browsers:

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
  if (this.isBrowser) {
    this.directionsService.getDirections(this.region).then(data => { this.directions = data; });
  }
}
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working...
The browser still loading a couple of seconds before rendering anything.
Prerendering doesn't help here because the catalogue has a lot of search parameters and it is difficult render all values

Comment: It's a bit unclear. What's taking 5 seconds? Client side search request? Loading the whole page? Are you always displaying 10000 items on the page?

Comment: It takes approx 5s to process request on the server-side due to high number of items in database and search properties

Comment: If the server is performing a search when the user first displays the page, then with your code you'll have the search performed twice (once server side and once client side). You need to use StateTransfer to avoid doing a client side search in this case. BUt the best way would be to improve your search query